# Jetpack Compose TextStyle

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Could anyone can tell me what's different in merge() and copy() with LoaclTextStyle.It seems the same.
Which one should I call when I want to change the text style in the @Composable scope?

I see ProvideTextStyle() method use the merge().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `merge()` method is used to create a new `TextStyle` by combining the properties of an existing `TextStyle` instance with another `TextStyle` instance.
This is useful when you want to combine multiple styles.

The `copy()` method is used to create a new `TextStyle` by copying the properties of the existing instance and changing some of them. This is useful when you want to make minor changes to an existing `TextStyle`.
To give an example to better understand the `copy()` function: `Copy()` also works when we using a `states`. It's like changing just one field without disturbing the existing `state`. This is the desired situation. Otherwise, you have reset all data.

Which one you use as a result is entirely up to you and what you want in your project.